# how to get all real solutions of polinomial equations?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, equation, polynomials

I have to find ALL solutions in a given interval of a polynomial equation. I use numpy.roots, but it gives me a lot of complex solutions which are not necessary. So how do I get rid of these complex solutions. The real solutions are also given in complex form

Comment: I wrote a ruby gem, which calculates accurate roots and curvature points for polynomials up to level 4. https://rubygems.org/gems/polynomials

Comment: Thanks, but I need it for degrees higher than 4,

Comment: There are no known exact solutions for polynomials higher than level 4. You'll only get estimations.

Comment: I know, but I don't need an exact solution, I just need an aproximate. I don't even need all solutions, just in a given interval.